# What is the runtime environment of the %postinstall item in EPM

Tags: packaging

According to the [EPM documentation](http://www.epmhome.org/epm-book.html#5_3) it's possible in BSD packages to run a script post-installation. I'd like to invoke a script installed as part of the package, if possible, but to do so I need to know a few things about the runtime:

1. What user will run the script?
2. What environment variables are set when it runs?
3. What is the CWD when the script runs?

Answer (score 0):

1: root

2 and 3:  I don't know, but you could add a post install script to your package that pipes the output of 'env' and 'pwd' to /tmp/env_and_pwd.txt.